# How to manipulate embeded svg node using react?

Tags: svg, reactjs

I got in trouble during developing react. I use

```
<img src="example.svg">
```

Or using module 'react-inlinesvg' to embed the svg

```
<Isvg src="example.svg" wrapper={React.DOM.div}>
```

i want to manipulate the`<g>`node of the svg file directly in react, add and remove class(ps: it's quite easy in JQuery). I tried to get the ref of the element but failed. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- Use some kind of query selectors;
- User react for writing SVG;

I would recommend you using 2nd approach. If you want to manipulate your own SVG, you can just write them in React as a component and work as you work with other React components.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#svg-elements) you can see a list of supported elements in React.

Comment: I prefer the 1st approach, but query selector seems not work well in react component. For the 2nd, when I rewrite the svg, I find there are many format error, and it will make the component a little messy. I wonder if there is any better way to manipulate the dom node in svg directly. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: React has nothing to do with your svg if you use first approach. jQuery selector is a selector a well, apparently sometimes built on top of native query selector. If you really want to use selectors - use jQuery, but I don't see any reason for that if you already use React.
Why the component should be messy? It should be 95% the same as the original SVG.

Comment: Breaking a big svg to components will make code file too large, and when i divide the svg into several components, there will be many format errors in attribute 'd'(I have already tried) and many tags must be replaced to the accepted tags in React. the work seems to be pretty awful. I see the JQuery manipulate the dom node very easily, so I wonder if there is a way like JQuery in React. However, I found nothing. Anyway, Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to use this:http://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm? Maybe it can help you.